# Compute $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{dt}{(5+2\cos t)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Where to start with this integral? I notice the function is entire, so it has an antiderivative and is path independent, but I am unsure of how to proceed.

$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{dt}{(5+2\cos t)^2}$$

Comment: Can you compute $$\oint_C\frac{dz}{z(5+z+1/z)^2}$$ where $C$ denotes the unit circle?

Comment: the solution should be $$\frac{5 \pi }{21 \sqrt{21}}$$

Comment: @Did, how to proceed after parameterization with $z=e^{i\theta}$ giving $\int_0^{2pi} \frac{idz}{(5+e^{iz}+1/(e^{iz}))^2}$?

Should I expand and break into partial fractions?

Comment: Sorry but if you fail to see how $$5+z+1/z$$ and $$5+2\cos t$$ are related when $z$ is on the unit circle...

Comment: I am seeing that they are equal on the unit circle, but not seeing how this helps me.

Comment: Have a look at pages 45-46 here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio This will take me a while to parse through, but it looks like an instructive addition to the answers I've received. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but at the end of the day, are you after a solution using complex analysis or are you not? FYI, the tag (complex-analysis), which you used, does **not** mean that the question pertains to analysis and that it is *complicated*...

Comment: @Did I now understand your hint, but am struggling to integrate the new integral $\displaystyle\int_{C} \dfrac{dz}{z(5+z+1/z)^2}$ over the top half-circle from 1 to -1.

Comment: @Did In particular, since $f(z)$ is not analytic at $z_0 = 0$, many useful theorems do not apply (or, am I mistaken that I cannot use substitution, antiderivatives and the FToC?) EDIT: The seemingly obvious $u = z^2 + 5z +1$ seems to get me nowhere.

Comment: The function $$f(z)=\frac1{z(5+z+1/z)^2}=\frac{z}{(5z+z^2+1)^2}$$ seems quite analytic at $z=0$ to me. Note also that $C$ denotes the full circle, not any half circle.

Comment: ((I duly note that you avoid to answer my request to explain whether you are after a solution using complex analysis or not.))

Comment: @Did Yes, ultimately I was, but since your hint didn't click at the time and you seemed reluctant to provide further assistance, I looked elsewhere and just shut this thread down. 

With regards to the problem: since the substitution is $z=e^{it}$, and $0<=t<=\pi$, shouldn't $1<=z<=-1$ along the unit circle (aka the half circle)?

Assuming C is the full circle, Residue Theorem at $z_0=\frac{-5+\sqrt{21}}{2}$ 
 indeed gives me something similar to the correct answer but with an extra $2i$ in the numerator (from $I = 2\pi i Res(f, z_0)$, $Res = \frac{5}{21\sqrt{21}}$).

Comment: You have a strange way of rewriting the facts... Anyway, one does not have to "assume" that C is the full circle since C is **defined as the full circle** from the start. And yes the factor 2 is there, and this should not come as a surprise since the full circle is made of two semi circles, right? Re solutions with residues vs with no residue as below, next time you wish to accept an answer with no residue, you might want to avoid pointing exclusively at solutions with residues in the question. Natural, no?

Comment: @Did Just to reiterate, I accepted an answer with no residues just for the sake of accepting an answer and closing the discussion, since it was obvious it was getting me nowhere. With regards to your answer, how can you define C to be the circle? Doesn't parameterizing with $z=e^{it}$ force $e^{i0}\leqslant z \leqslant e^{i\pi}$, which is the unit half-circle? Is it a well known fact that if $I$ is the contour integral of $f$ along a circle $C$, then the integral $I'$ of $f$ along half of $C$ is $I/2$? If so, what to do about the factor of $i$?

Comment: ?? You accepted the answer below **11 minutes** after it was posted. Is this what you call being "obvious it was getting me nowhere"? Sorry but you are not making much sense, hence I have little incentive to explain the half circle vs circle difference which seems to distress you so much (whose explanation is trivial, however).

Comment: Honesty would suggest that you at least add a mention to your question, to the effect that in fact residue approaches **do not** interest you.

Comment: @Did "Sorry but if you fail to see how... [you are beyond help (implied)]". Well, at the time I didn't, and while I do not understand complex analysis well at all, I do understand modus ponens. So I accepted the first answer that came and moved on with my life. Thanks for the help though, I do unsarcastically appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** without complex analysis.

Using Feynman's trick of differentiating under the integral. $$I(a)=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{dt}{(5+a\cos t)^2}=-\frac d{da} \int_0^{\pi} \frac{dt}{5+a\cos t}$$ could be an interesting solution.

Comment: Strangely enough, I answered this exact question (save for a few constants) not so long ago! https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2389032/99916

Comment: Seems that I didn't do my due diligence. Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @Kari. Amazing ! By the way, you made a nice answer (which I upvoted).

Comment: Thanks, @ClaudeLeibovici. Hopefully somebody can offer a complex analytic solution. I'm curious to see how it's done.

Comment: @Kari Re your query in the chat, of course "there is a complex analytic way to deal with that integral". This way starts with the integral in my first comment on main and it then follows a ultra-standard approach. But, as you surely have noted, the OP does not seem interested, hence I see no reason to bother them with it... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempted solution without complex analysis's techniques:

For $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{(5+2\cos{x})^2}dx$ we can take the Weierstass substitution:

Put $t=\tan{\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{\sin{(x/2)}}{\cos{(x/2)}}$

It is proved that $$\sin{x}= \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$ $$\cos{x}=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$  $$dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$$

For $x \rightarrow \pi^- \Rightarrow \tan{(x/2)} \rightarrow + \infty \Rightarrow t \rightarrow \infty$

For $x=0 \Rightarrow t=0$

Thus we have to solve the integral: $$\int_0^{+ \infty} \frac{2(1+t^2)}{(7+3t^2)^2}dt$$

which can be solved with the partial fraction  method.

Comment: I suppose that you missed the square in the integrand $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{dt}{(5+2\cos t)^\color{red}{2}}$

Comment: Yes you are correct..thank you..i will edit it.